# how to use browserify in windows

Tags: windows, browserify

I am trying browserify and I have the following files in my project directory

- node_models/.bin - where browserify is located
- sample.js

  ```
  module.exports = 'Hello, world';
  ```
- index.js

  ```
  window.alert(require('./sample'));
  ```

Can somebody help me how to run it using browserify? I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you should need to do is run this command in the project directory:

```
node_modules\.bin\browserify index.js > bundle.js
```

However, you can make things a little more convinient by adding an entry under `scripts` in your `package.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "bundle": "browserify index.js > bundle.js"
    }
}
```

You can then build the bundle with this command:

```
npm run bundle
```

Comment: I tried the first command. It gives me the following error: DeprecationWarning: Using Buffer without 'new' will soon stop working. Use 'new Buffer()', or preferably 'Buffer.from()', 'Buffer.allocUnsafe()' or 'Buffer.alloc()' instead.

Comment: What versions are you using? `node --version` and `browserify --version`

Comment: Well, it's a *warning*. Try updating Browserify. The latest major version is now up to 13.